# How to insert string1 after 1st occurrence of string, string2 after 2nd occurrence of string, and so on?

Tags: python-3.x, string

I have a large string `content2` in which the substring `<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound">` appears 5 times. Moreover, I have a column `sound_url['CODE']` with 5 rows, each of which contaning a string.

Could you please help me add the string in row 1 right after the 1st `<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound">`, the string in row 2 right after the 2nd `<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound">`, and so on?

Below is my full code

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import re

url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/graduate'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers = headers).content, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('''
        script,
        div.mpuslot_b-container,
        div.h2_entry,
        div.copyright,
        div.example-info,
        div.share-overlay,
        div.popup-overlay,
        span.xr'''):
    tag.extract()  

entry_name = soup.h2.text    
content1 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling').contents))
content2 = str(content1)

sound_url = pandas.DataFrame(re.findall('data-src-mp3="(.*?)"', content2))
sound_url.rename(columns = {0: 'LINK'}, inplace = True)
sound_url['NAME'] = sound_url['LINK'].str.split('/', expand = True)[5]
sound_url['CODE'] = '<a href="sound://' + sound_url['NAME'] + '">keyword</a>'

print(sound_url['CODE'])
```

Here is the column `sound_url['CODE']`:

```
0    <a href="sound://EN-GB-W0037420.mp3">keyword</a>
1       <a href="sound://FR-W0037420.mp3">keyword</a>
2       <a href="sound://FR-W0071410.mp3">keyword</a>
3      <a href="sound://fr_bachelier.mp3">keyword</a>
4             <a href="sound://63854.mp3">keyword</a>
```

---

**Update:** Let me explain my expected output:

Assume that `content2 = .....<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound">.....<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound">.....<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound">.....<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound">.....<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound">.....`.

Then my expected output is `.....<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound"><a href="sound://EN-GB-W0037420.mp3">keyword</a>.....<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound"><a href="sound://FR-W0037420.mp3">keyword</a>.....<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound"><a href="sound://FR-W0071410.mp3">keyword</a>...<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound"><a href="sound://fr_bachelier.mp3">keyword</a>.....<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound"><a href="sound://63854.mp3">keyword</a>.....`.

Comment: Maybe I don't understand you well...what's the expected output? Can you edit your question and put it there?

Comment: @AndrejKesely Please see my edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if I understood your question right, but this script will add the contents of `sound_url['CODE']` to each `<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound">`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import re

url = 'https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/graduate'
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:78.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/78.0'}
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers = headers).content, 'html.parser')

for tag in soup.select('''
        script,
        div.mpuslot_b-container,
        div.h2_entry,
        div.copyright,
        div.example-info,
        div.share-overlay,
        div.popup-overlay,
        span.xr'''):
    tag.extract()

entry_name = soup.h2.text
content1 = ''.join(map(str, soup.select_one('.cB.cB-def.dictionary.biling').contents))
content2 = str(content1)

sound_url = pandas.DataFrame(re.findall('data-src-mp3="(.*?)"', content2))
sound_url.rename(columns = {0: 'LINK'}, inplace = True)
sound_url['NAME'] = sound_url['LINK'].str.split('/', expand = True)[5]
sound_url['CODE'] = '<a href="sound://' + sound_url['NAME'] + '">keyword</a>'

soup2 = BeautifulSoup(content2, 'html.parser')

for tag, l in zip(soup2.select('.ptr.hwd_sound.type-hwd_sound'),  sound_url['CODE']):
    tag.insert(0, BeautifulSoup(l, 'html.parser'))

print(soup2)
```

Prints:

```
...

<span class="ptr hwd_sound type-hwd_sound"><a href="sound://EN-GB-W0037420.mp3">keyword</a>
<a class="hwd_sound sound audio_play_button icon-volume-up ptr" data-lang="en_GB" data-src-mp3="https://www.collinsdictionary.com/sounds/hwd_sounds/EN-GB-W0037420.mp3" title="Pronunciation for "></a>
</span></span><span class="punctuation">]</span></span>

...
```